# Unable to choose by selectors using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a problem with getting elements by their selectors.

A page on which I struggle is: http://html5.haxball.com/.
What I have succeded is to log in, but that was kind of a hack, because I used the fact, that the field I need to fill is already selected.

After typing in nick and going into lobby I want to click the button 'Create room'. Its selector:
body > div > div > div > div > div.buttons > button:nth-child(3)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox'], headless: false, slowMo: 10
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://html5.haxball.com/index.html');
await page.keyboard.type(name);
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
//at this point I am logged in.

let buttonSelector = 'body > div > div > div > div > div.buttons > button:nth-child(3)';

await page.waitForSelector('body > div > div');
await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector(buttonSelector).click();
});

browser.close();
})();
```

after running such code I get error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

My initial approach was with:
    await page.click(buttonSelector);
instead of page.evaluate but it also fails.

What frustrates my the most is the fact that when I run in Chromium console:
    document.querySelector(buttonSelector).click();
it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to note:

- The selector you are using to retrieve the button is more complex than it needs to be. Try something simpler like: `'button[data-hook="create"]'`.
- The game is within an `iframe`, so you're better off calling `document.querySelector` using the `iframe`'s `document` object as opposed to the containing window's `document`
- The function passed to `evaluate` is executed in a different context than where you are running your node script. For this reason, you have to explicitly pass variables from your node script to the window script otherwise `buttonSelector` will be undefined:

Making the changes above, your code will input your name and successfully click on "Create Room":

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox'], headless: false, slowMo: 10
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://html5.haxball.com/index.html');
    await page.keyboard.type('Chris');
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    //at this point I am logged in.

    let buttonSelector = 'button[data-hook="create"]';

    await page.waitForSelector('body > div > div');

    await page.evaluate((buttonSelector) => {

        var frame = document.querySelector('iframe');

        var frameDocument = frame.contentDocument;

        frameDocument.querySelector(buttonSelector).click();

    }, buttonSelector);

    browser.close();

})();
```